# Dialog open twice on fast click of button

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I have `Button`, which on clicking, displays a `Dialog`. Everything works like a charm, but if I double click the button or click the button fast, the `Dialog` opens two or three times. I have to click the back button twice or thrice to dismiss the `Dialog`.

I have searched for related questions on *SO*, but most of the answers suggest **disabling the button or to use a variable and setting it to true and false**, which is not my requirement.

If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please help me.

**Code I have used**

```
// Delete item on click of delete button
holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);      
        passwordDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: how about making code inside `onClick()` synchronized, and putting an check for if the dialog is already open.

Comment: Dayuuuum! you are way too faster than a processor ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to just check **whether your `Dialog` is already shown or not**:

```
Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);
holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                  
        if(!passwordDialog.isShowing()) {
            passwordDialog.show();
        }
    }
});
```

**Update:**

If this doesn't work in your case, then in your activity **declare globally**:

```
Dialog passwordDialog = null;
```

and on `Button`'s click:

```
holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                  
        if(passwordDialog == null) {
            passwordDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this); 
            passwordDialog.show(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I used this...it works but sometimes on fast click it show dialog twice...that's why i posted the question.

Comment: But in my Dialog passwordDialog is a local variable...as i used in one place only so i dont declare it globally

Comment: I tried your code..so what happend it open the dialog, and as i dismiss the dialog using ok or back button and again tried to open the dialog it doesn't open..becoz it doesnt found dialog null

Comment: In **ok** or **back** button make it `null` simple ..:-)

Comment: Ok thats fine but how to make it null on click of device back button.

Comment: On ok and cancel button i make it null and its working...but i am not able to make it null on click of device back button when dialog is open...becoz it not calling the onBackpressed() method when dialog is open and i press the back button.

Comment: Add this code on button's click, `passwordDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {         
       @Override
       public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        passwordDialog = null;
       }
   });`

Answer (score 9):

Declared globally:

```
private Boolean dialogShownOnce = false;
private mDialog dia;
```

Where your `dialog.show();` is called:

```
dia = new mDialog(getContext());

if (!dia.isShowing() && !dialogShownOnce) {
    dia.show();
    dialogShownOnce = true;
}

dia.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        dialogShownOnce = false;
    }
});
```

mDialog does not have to be global, but I was calling `mDialog.dismiss()` in some out-of-local-scope interfaces.

Still uses a `Boolean`, but I don´t understand why it can´t be used.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code where you want to show dialog, it checks exist dialog base on its tag name.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment prevFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
if (prevFragment != null) {
    return;
}

MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance();
dialog.show(ft, "dialog");
```

Answer (score 1):

disable the button once you clicked it and enable again once you cancel the dialog. like below

```
 holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {   
                    holder.butDelete.setEnabled(false);
                    Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);      
                    passwordDialog.show();
                }
            });
```

if it didn't work you have to take one boolean variable and use that to show and cancel the dialog.

Comment: I dont think u read my question...i have written in bold letter about this.

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `show()` method it takes a little while to `isShowing()` returns the *true*. 
At first, it returns *false* because the dialog entrance animation doesn't finish yet. 
My solution is about building a new implementation of the dialog class.

```
public class ObedientDialog extends Dialog{

    private boolean showing;

    public ObedientDialog(Context context) {

        setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                showing=false;
            }});

        setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                showing=false;
            }});
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        if (!showing) super.show();
        showing=true;
    }

    public boolean isShowing(){
        return showing;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. That's how I fixed it

```
private AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
private AlertDialog alertDialog;
```

Declare the above variables globally

```
alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Then like above create **alertDialogBuilder** in the **OnCreate** method

```
    private void AlertDialogMessage(){
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Internet disconnected!");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
   }
```

We have just baked our alert dialog in this function. Call this function in the **OnCreate** method.
It should be called after the **alertDialogBuilder** creation statement. After that in your button **OnClickListener** put that below code.

```
   if (!alertDialog.isShowing()){
        alertDialog.show();
   }
```

That's it. It fixed my issue. Hopefully, it will fix yours too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code given below

```
 private long mLastClickTime = 0;

public boolean isSingleClick() {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
                return false;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            return true;
        }

    if(isSingleClick){
    openDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably have your dialogs managed by your activity, by overriding `onCreateDialog()` method and then calling `showDialog()`. That would solve your problem.

See [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog(int, android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

> Callback for creating dialogs that are managed (saved and restored) for you by the activity. The default implementation calls through to onCreateDialog(int) for compatibility. If you are targeting HONEYCOMB or later, consider instead using a DialogFragment instead.

Example:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private static final int TEST_DIALOG_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    showDialog(TEST_DIALOG_ID);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if(id == TEST_DIALOG_ID) {
        Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(this);      
        return passwordDialog;
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.

**Step 1.** Declare dialog object as instance variable or global variable

```
  private MediaPlayerDialog dialog;
```

**Step 2.** now put below code in you btton click.

```
 if (dialog == null || (!dialog.isVisible())) {
        dialog = new MediaPlayerDialog();
        dialog.setData(songListDatas, selectPosition);
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), dialog.getClass().getName().toString());
    }
```

**Note :** `MediaPlayer` is my custom `DialogFragment` you can change it according to your requirement.

**Best of Luck**

Answer (score -2):

try like this...

```
Dialog passwordDialog = new Dialog(SettingsActivity.this);


holder.butDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {                         
                if(!passwordDialog.isShowing()) {   
                   passwordDialog.show();
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: This will never work, `passwordDialog.isShowing()` is called on a freshly created instance each time.